# Togglear requestAnimationFrame on/off

Tags: javascript, web

Digamos que tengo mi animacion

```
function animation(){

    const animationId = requestAnimationFrame(animation)

    animarCosa()
    animarCosa1()

    }

animation()
```

Al llamar a animation() la animacion se ejecuta correctamente y sin problemas.
Pero lo que yo quiero hacer es que al presionar un boton la imagen se detenga, y al volver a pulsarlo se reanude donde estaba.

Para hacer esto he pensado en usar cancelAnimationFrame y hacer lo siguiente

```
function animation(){

    const animationId = requestAnimationFrame(animation)

    animarCosa()
    animarCosa1()

    if(sidebar.classList.contains('on')){
    window.cancelAnimationFrame(animationId)}

    // sidebar on/off se togglea al presionar el boton, por defecto esta off

    }

animation()
```

Con esto, al presionar mi boton y poner sidebar en 'on' la animacion se cancela correctamente. Pero no encuentro forma de reanudarla de nuevo. He probado a volver a llamar a animation() dentro de la misma funcion, a llamar a un nuevo request animation frame pero sin exito

Alguien tiene alguna idea?

Comment: ¿Has quitado la clase "on" de nuevo, para que no se cancele en cada llamada?

Answer (score 1):

Yo usé una clase (.stop) para ver si estaba la animación corriendo o no

```js
const cuadro = document.getElementById('cuadro');
let index=0;
let animacionID;
function animation(){
    cuadro.style.backgroundColor = "#" + index.toString(16).padStart(6, "0");
    index++;
    globalID = requestAnimationFrame(animation);
}
function onoff(boton){
  if(boton.classList.contains('stop')){
    globalID = requestAnimationFrame(animation);
  }
  else{
    cancelAnimationFrame(globalID);
  }
  boton.classList.toggle('stop');
}
```

```css
button:after{
 content:'Parar'
}

button.stop:after{
 content:'Iniciar'
}
#cuadro{
 height:100px;
width:100px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="onoff(this)" class="stop"></button>

<div id="cuadro"></div>
```